# how to get full URL from shortened URLs like bit.ly?

Tags: curl, url

- I have a shortened URL from some documentation
- I would like to open the URL because I believe the URL has good information
- but I do not want to click the link until I can see the full URL

#### how to get full URL from shortened URLs like bit.ly?

Answer (score 0):

#### I found a simple elegant solution using shell command:

##### `curl --head bitly.is/urlshortening|grep Location|awk '{print $2}'`

explanation of the shell command:

- `curl` with `--head` gets only the HTTP header
- `grep` gets you the line of text with URL value
- `awk` prints you just the URL value
- done

##### even shorter: `curl --head --location bitly.is/urlshortening`

The reason why using `curl` works is because the URL shortener is doing an [HTTP redirect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection) and so this solution uses the knowledge about [how HTTP redirects work](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection).

p.s. IMO `curl` is significantly better than a browser extension or third-party website because the `curl` solution is (1.) faster IMO than having to vet N browser-extensions/third-party-websites (2.) and the shell command is easy even for beginners (3.) browser-extensions/third-party-websites come and go.

Comment: you can also actually extract that header field using curl. No need to manually look for the Location field. add a `-L` to your command line

Comment: @MarcusMüller that triggers a HEAD on the target URL, which may have undesirable side-effects. Extracting the Location field from the bit.ly HEAD avoids that

Comment: @MarcusMüller thanks i'll add that.

Answer (score -1):

For Firefox:

- https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/short-url-expander/
- https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/url-revealer/
- https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/expand-url/

For Chrome based browsers:

- https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/preview-short-urls/lhnpeajamdliepjblldlghmpkohfjakb
- https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/unshortenit/lgmkbhnfldpklfakbcopgkkhonofficm

I've not tested any.

Curl: `curl -s -I "$URL" | awk '/location:/{print $2}'`

`wget` probably can do this as well (it has `-d`) but I'm half-asleep right now to read its manual.